# It is very unlikely a real number chosen between zero and one randomly be an element of Cantor set?

Tags: probability

It is very unlikely a real number chosen between zero and one randomly be in Cantor set? 
I know elements of Cantor set when we write the number in base three.
With the help of a program I chose 100 numbers at random and I actually found none of them is in Cantor set.
I could not come up with any other way.

Comment: Cantor set has measure zero so the probability of picking a number from the cantor set is zero

Comment: WHAT DOES MEASURE ZERO MEAN?

Comment: What do you know about the Cantor set?   The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) contains a discussion of it's measure theoretic properties, for instance.

Comment: Informally, if you think of the cantor set as those real numbers between $0$ and $1$ whose ternary expansion does not contain the digit $1$, then it is clear that the probability of randomly selecting one is $0$.  Consider the random number generator which uniformly and independently selects $0,1,2$ as the successive ternary digits.

Comment: That claim is meaningless until you define (and choose) a probability on a convenient collection of sets of $[0,1]$ that has the Cantor set $C$ as one of its elements. If I choose the collection of sets to be $\emptyset, C, C^c, [0,1]$ and define that the probability of $C$ and $[0,1]$ is $1$ and the probability of $\emptyset$ and $C^c$ is $0$, then the probability of picking an element of $[0,1]$ and this being in $C$ is $1$.

Comment: It is not impossible but the probability of occurrence equals $0$ if  the Lebesgue measure is practicized as probability measure on $[0,1]$. That is in this context the meaning of "measure zero". In your question you speak of "choosing randomly" which invites to practicize the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @conditionalMethod WHAT DOES THAT MEAN?

Comment: @Keon Are you familiar with probability measures? If so then why do you ask for the meaning. if not then what exactly do you mean with "randomly"?

Comment: @Keon Please don't type comments in all caps, it looks like shouting.

Comment: "random " has a common meaning@drhab  does it have any specific meaning. I produce a random #

Comment: Then I hope that my first comment on this question is enough for you to make things clear. If it is not then I encourage you to dive into things like (probability) measures. These are functions on specific sets. Probability theory formalizes concepts like "random" so that it can be used in mathematics on a proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you had written, I understand, that your random number $x$ is [uniformly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) between $0$ and $1$, which means, that for any $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ the probability of $x \in A$ is equal to $\mu(A\cap [0; 1])$, where $\mu$ stands for [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)). And Lebesgue measure of a Cantor set [is known to be zero](https://theoremoftheweek.wordpress.com/2010/09/30/theorem-36-the-cantor-set-is-an-uncountable-set-with-zero-measure/).